# list_empty function kernel linked list

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linked-list, kernel

`list_empty()` function is defined in `./include/linux/list.h` and its definition is

```
static inline int list_empty(const struct list_head *head)
{
    return head->next == head;
}
```

`list_head` data structure is defined as

```
struct list_head {
     struct list_head *next, *prev;
};
```

What I do not understand is why this implementation in kernel checks for `head->next == head` and not for `head->next == NULL` && `head->prev == NULL`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The list is circular, with the head itself serving as a dummy node.  Circular lists have a slight advantage in the number of comparisons needed during insertion and deletion.  Since there are no null pointers, there are not as many special cases to look for.  I don't have the source code here, but if you check it, you'll find that initializing a list is done with something like:

```
head->next = head->prev = head;
```

Insertion will be:

```
void insert_after(struct list_head *node, struct list_head *after)
{
  node->next = after->next;
  node->prev = after;
  after->next->prev = node;
  after->next = node; 
}
```

Look!  No if statements at all!

Answer (score 0):

because `head->next` is not `NULL` when the list is empty, it points to `head` instead.